# Ubuntu 13.04 don't boot with Windows 7

Tags: gnome, grub2, dual-boot, windows, 13.04

So I just installed the Gnome, I used the Gparted to make the partitions because the basic mode to install side by side with windows was not working. Ok, I made the partitions and installed, no problem. But the dual boot it's not working, runs directly the Windows 7. The bios setup I also can't config the 2nd boot with the Ubuntu partition, only shows the first one and de DVD drive. My motherboard it's a Gigabyte Mini.

I tried to found here someone that had the same problem but no results.

Anyone can help? Thanks!

Comment: Gnome is a DE. Please specify which Ubuntu edition you've installed with Gnome.

Comment: Ubuntu 13.04 amd 64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you partitioned the disk yourself, or did you just shrink the Windows partition? Best way is to just shrink it and leave room at the end of the disk so the installer can partition it.

Next you should choose install in the live-CD (on USB or whatever) and have choose 'something else' in the installer.

Then you should specify the partitions you would like to use (or free space), if you'd like to partition this partition, how big it should be and where to mount them.

You should at least have the / partition chosen somewhere. (a couple of GB is enough)
Advisable is a separate /home partition. (because re-installing is much simpler then)
Choose to partition them to ext4.

The installer should install grub for the whole disk. If it ask for it, choose install for all partitions.

Comment: I made the partitions using the Gparted, one with 10gb for the Root and 250gb for the Home Partition, all in ext4. After that I installed in the option 'Something Else'. But I don't know, the Grub it's not working. My friends told me to install the Grub or Lilo, but how am I going to install if I can't run the Ubuntu?

Comment: You can boot from the live cd.
Something like this:
http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/245

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem. But it didn't worked in 13.04, only in the 12.04 LTS. I followed the instructions from this video to install the GRUB https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-7HuurWJTJ4 (it's in portuguese but I think it's easy to everybody understand).

So tried to install the GRUB in 13.04 version but it won't work. So I downloaded and installed the 12.04 LTS version. Got the same problem with the dual boot at the end, so I tried again to install the GRUB following the instructions in the video and worked. I hope it help others and sorry about the bad english hahaha.